# Store the output values from a random sample

Tags: random

I am new to programming. I am defining x and y as random samples(as mentioned). Then I define a function h (of x and y). Now I want to get output values of h multiple times at once. I want to store them and use them later to plot a histogram. I have written this code.[image]

I want to store these values in a single array (rather than in different arrays as I'm getting here in output) and use them later.

Please help me out!!!

Comment: Type `Table` and hit `F1`. p.s. explain "not correct".

Comment: Thanks man... and it was correct, I was just mistaken.

Comment: `store these values in a single array` you can try `Join` ?

Comment: Btw.: Mathematica is not Maple. Please use `=` instead of `:=` for assignments of constants and `==` or `===` instead of `=` for comparisons. See also the documentations of `Set`, `SetDelayed`, `Equal`, and `SameQ` to find out more about this.